# Force program to use java instead of java 8

Tags: java, deployment, version, java-web-start

I have a program (xx.jnlp) run by Webstart. This application must use Java 1.7.0_71. (32bit) But when Java 8 (64bit) is installed it tries to start with it.

I have found out it can be controlled by Java Control Panel (user) and through deployment.properties and deployment.config

my question is now. How to define the code inside deployment.properties and deployment.config to run a specified program(xx.jnlp) with an specified java version (In this case 1.7.0_71 32bit)

i tried with this line in deployment.properties.
"deployment.javaws.jre = 1.7.0_71 /jnpl=http://XX.jnlp / arch = x86 "

Maybe i need to do something inside deployment.config

Best Regards

Comment: I believe you set that up in the Java web start control panel.

Comment: But what i need is to set it up from deployment.properties and deployment.config

Comment: I do not believe that is possible. Maybe someone will answer with a way.

Comment: I don't know anything about WebStart, but often you use the JAVA_HOME variable to control things like this.  I'd try setting it to the root of your 32 bit Java install.  For example, on mine I've got  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67

Comment: i know but other program that will be run should use java8

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your jnlp file:

```
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.7.0_71" arch="x86" />
</resources>
```

As described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources). Maybe you need to test several options, before this will work properly.

Comment: Im not able to change the program file.